# Is the Wordpress Nonce authentication enough for admin plugin REST calls

Tags: wordpress, security, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have a plugin which also has some admin pages. These pages require some ajax calls that should be authenticated. So if the admin is logged in, these ajax calls are valid, and otherwise they should not be honored.

The question is that is Wordpress Nonce enough to apply this kind of authentication?

I have checked it practically and it works! If I am logged out, the admin ajax calls fail, and thus unauthorized access is prohibited.

I still want to know the best practice and confirm if any of you experts think it is ok to use just Nonce or I must use some other authentication method as well?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think your question is on-topic here... Maybe [wordpress.se] or [security.se]

Comment: @brasofilo ok, thanks. I will post it there